# How to: Setting an Expires Response Header for a Views block?

Tags: views, blocks, caching

On another question I received the following advice:

> Create a module drupal generate:module, create the route subscriber drupal generate:route subscriber and to look up the route name of the view drupal router:debug
>
> ...
>
> setting an Expires Response Header

How can I Do that?
Composer and Console are running with Acquia-dev-desktop.
I've created a first "mymodule" with "implement method: hello".
So I have come a lot further than I was yesterday.

Do you have a guide for me?

Best regards

Frank

PS: I discovered the [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ape) "Advanced Page Expiration".
This will probably only be for pages, not for blocks?